# Linear optimization: is it possible to implement "$\min$" function linearly?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization

I am working on an Optimization problem with an objective function that includes a "min" function. Consider $g$ as a discrete bounded function. The value of $g(i)$ must be ignored if $g(i)>0$ and must be considered if $g(i)<0$. 
In other words, if we show the objective function by $f$, the objective is

$$\max_{i}  f(i)  =  \left\{ f_1(i) + \min (0,g(i))\right\}$$

How the $\min$ function can be implemented in the objective function linearly?
Is it possible to use an auxiliary variable like $z_i$ as

$$ \max_{i,z_i}  f(i) = \left\{f_1(i) - z_i\right\}$$
subject to:

\begin{align}
z_i &\ge 0, \\[0.2cm]
z_i &\ge -g(i)
\end{align}

Thanks.

Comment: I assume that you know the values of $g$, so if you need to implement it in a program, you can actually just redefine $g$ as $h=g$ whenever $g<0$ and $h=0$ whenever $g\ge 0$.

Comment: @Jimmy-r your reformulation results in a nondifferentiable function which may cause problems for optimization algorithms.

Comment: @LinAlg Ah, yes ok..., what? $h$ is a function exactly as $g$. So, if $g$ the problem is differentiable with $g$ (I do not know what you mean with this) so it is with $h$.

Comment: @Jimmy-r for example, if $g(x)=x$, your $h$ is nondifferentiable at $0$.

Comment: @LinAlg But $g$ is a discrete function, defined only at $i\in \mathbb N$ (or in some discrete set). I think it is not differentiable in the first place, or am I wrong?

Comment: Right. The goal of the reformulation is beyond me now.

Comment: @LinAlg You both are right. In this case of discrete $g$ where I have to replace them before using and reformulation is not needed. For the case of continues $g$ the reformulation is valid, right?

Comment: The reformulation is valid in both cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reformulation is correct, although the subscript for $z$ is not necessary. Note that the reformulation is only correct since your objective is maximization. It is less confusing to have $z=\min(0, g(i))$ (you have it as the negative of this expression): $\max_{i, z} \{ f_1(i)+z \; : \;  z \leq 0, \; z \leq g(i)\}$

Comment: Thanks. The formulation you suggested is easier.